# What is proper way to reuse socket between promise executor function invocations?

Tags: node.js, sockets, async-await

I want to reuse the same socket across all `Promise` executor function invocations. However, this socket reuse introduces a new problem that once a response comes in from the sever, the right `Promise` must be `resolve()`d.

So I came up with following design to `resolve()` only the right promise:

```js
const dgram = require('dgram');

const socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

async function lookup(id) {
  socket.send(JSON.stringify({ "id": id }), "10000", "127.0.0.1");
  let p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    socket.on("message", (msg, rinfo) => {
      let response = JSON.parse(msg)
      if (response.id === id) {// resolve only one response
        resolve(response.value);
      }
    })
  })
  let value = await p;
  console.log(`resolved ${id} to ${value}`)
}

lookup("1")
lookup("2")
```

However, the design above still has shortcomings. On each incoming UDP message from the server the program will call the "message" event handler for each `Promise` that is still in pending state. This is quite inefficient if server went down for brief time or if the `lookup()` function was invoked in bursts.

So I came up with second design below where the `resolve()` function is stored in a global `PromiseMap` and once the response comes in, the right `resolve()` function is called from a single handler:

```js
const dgram = require('dgram');

const socket = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

var PromiseMap = {}

async function lookup(id) {
  socket.send(JSON.stringify({"id":id}), "10000", "127.0.0.1");
  let p = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      PromiseMap[id] = resolve;
  })
  let value = await p;
  console.log(`resolved ${id} to ${value}`)
}

socket.on("message", (msg, rinfo) => {
  let response = JSON.parse(msg)
  if (response.id in PromiseMap) {
    PromiseMap[response.id](response.value);
  }
  delete PromiseMap[response.id]
})

lookup("1")
lookup("2")
```

This seems to work. However, I am wondering what is generally accepted way to reuse sockets across `Promise`s?

The protocol in my simplified example above looks like this:

```
nc -u -l 10000
{"id":"1"}{"id":"2"} <---two requests coming in from client
{"id":"2", "value":"a"} <---Response two comes in first
{"id":"1", "value":"b"} <--- only then response to first request comes in
```

Comment: In the above code you're just creating a single socket and sending message on each call of lookup() function with that socket, I didn't your mean of reusing sockets

Comment: Or the above whole script run for each new connection?

Comment: @Basit, not sure I understand your comment - are you asking what I meant with "reusing single socket"? If so, then in both code examples above a global socket is being created on line 3. Hence socket is being reused across multiple Promise instances. Alternatively, I could have written code where socket is created from executor function that I pass to Promise(). Then it would not be reused.

Comment: The first approach is quite unusable but the second flow is quite good creating a promise map and on socket message just resolving specific promise.

In your second flow socket is also global (reusable) and code wise it would work fine as expected